# The user cannot start a task on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

Why would a user who is a member of the 'backup operator' group be unable to run a task? It simply does not start - there is no error that I can find. I changed the user of the Windows Server Backup from admin to svc_backup to avoid changing the password periodically in two places (svc_backup has a non expiring passsword) but the svc_backup user cannot start the backup task.

What can I check?

Comment: Have you looked in the event log?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is it backing up? User data, systemstate or system files?

Comment: Event viewer says: `The backup operation that started at '‎2012‎-‎01‎-‎23T11:14:28.091199900Z' has failed because the Windows Server Backup engine could not be contacted, error code '2155413596'. Please confirm that the service is installed and enabled, and then rerun the backup operation.`...

Answer (score 1):

Check that the Backup Operators group has been granted the "Logon as a batch job" windows right.  This is the default, but may have been changed.

Also, try to right-click on the task and select Run to determine if it launches in that scenario.

I would also select "Run with highest privileges" and "Run whether the user is logged on or not".

Comment: Double check everything but it doens't work...